# Ubuntu 12.04 compiling a C program

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit desktop version and I wrote a computer program where it uses the math.h head, and I keep getting an error saying that it is an undefined reference to 'pow'. I compliled it using `gcc -Wall -lm filex.c -o filex.out`.
I really like this new system but what can be going wrong? All forums I have looked at just say to compile using `-lm` which I am. I have compiled the same program in another computer and it works just fine. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I met a same problem, and found your question by search engine.
I solve the problem by moving the option "-lm" to the last part of the command.

Please try the following command:

```
gcc -Wall filex.c -o filex.out -lm
```